# printing log statements using { } instead of concatenating

Tags: logging, slf4j

We use slf4j for logging. I see sometimes log statements are provided as :

```
log.info("Something like this {}", variable);
```

Whereas, other times, we concatenate :

```
log.info("Something like this " + variable);
```

What is the difference between these two ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case

```
log.info("Something like this {}", variable);
```

first `info` argument is a template string. Internally log4j will use the rest of parameters to fill the placeholders in the corresponding order.

In the second case

```
log.info("Something like this " + variable);
```

the `StringBuilder` will be used to assemble the message string and the result will be used as your log message.

There are at least 2 reasons for using the first variant:

1) The message is not processed unless it is to be written to appender.

Using template string delays the message processing and the rendering will be done only if the log is actually to be written ([javadoc ref](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html#info(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))).

In the second case the message will be assembled even when you logging level isn't high enough for the log to be printed.

2) Improved readability

To feel the difference you should consider a bit more complex example:

```
log.info("A is {} and B is {}. The difference is {}.", a, b, a-b);
```

vs

```
log.info("A is " + a + " and B is " + b + ". The difference is " + (a-b) + ".");
```